# QtQuick Application wont run on VMWare (Virtual Machine)

Tags: virtual-machine, qml, qtquick2, egl

**Build System:**

- Qt Creator 2.7.2 Based on Qt 5.1.0 (32 bit) Built on Jul 2 2013
- Qt 5.1.0 MSVC2010 32bit (ANGLE)
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (7.1.7600.0.30514)

**Environment:**

- Windows 7 (VMWare)

**Problem:**
A new Qt Quick 2 Application (Built-in Elements) project will not run as I receive:

```
class QWindowsEGLStaticContext *__cdecl QWindowsEGLStaticContext::create(void): Could not initialize egl display: error 12289

QOpenGLFunctions created with non-current context 
List of attribute names is either too long or not null-terminated.
Maximum number of attributes on this hardware is 0.
Vertex shader:
attribute highp vec4 vertexCoord;              
attribute highp vec4 vertexColor;              
uniform highp mat4 matrix;                     
uniform highp float opacity;                   
varying lowp vec4 color;                       
void main() {                                  
    gl_Position = matrix * vertexCoord;        
    color = vertexColor * opacity;             
}
Fragment shader:
varying lowp vec4 color;                       
void main() {                                  
    gl_FragColor = color;                      
}
```

I believe this is due to it running on a virtual machine.

I have tried both ANGLE and OpenGL versions of Qt but both fail. The OpenGL I expected to fail as I don't believe our VMWare infrastructure has a compatible video driver.

Has anyone else experienced this and managed to work around it?

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: The support for opengl on virtual machines is usually very minimal. I have not been able to make my app run either. I tried a year ago with Oracle "virtual box"

Comment: Thanks Jay. I did manage to get this working after discussing it with my IT department. They enabled the 3D Graphics support and it worked. I'm now in discussions with them regarding what impact this is going to have as the actual VM Server doesn't have 3D Graphics cards so it's having to use the CPU for rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by activating "Accelerate 3D graphics" in vmplayer conf.
After that, I don't have the error message, but the apps still doesn't work: it display a blank screen.

Comment: Hi Trey. Thanks for getting back to me. I managed to get this working but there's the battle of what we're going to need within our Physical underlying infrastructure to support this. Hope you managed to solve the blank screen issue.

Comment: In my case, I have to uncheck "Accelerate 3D graphics" to make the qml program display properly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the missing of d3dcompiler, provided by [DirectX End-User Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/it-it/download/details.aspx?id=35), as remarked by Friedemann Kleint's comment on [QTBUG-31611](https://snusmumriken.qtproject.c.bitbit.net/browse/QTBUG-31611). I had the same problem (a blank window) and installing DirectX and reboot the system, has been the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Installation of a NVIDIA graphic acceleration + the related NVIDIA Software driver of the graphic card will fix the problem after a restart of the PC